# Soft real time operating systems

Tags: operating-systems

I know the basic idea and difference between hard and soft RTOS.

I wanted to know a large scale and specific example of soft RTOS. I read in this site that even LINUX is a soft RTOS.

Is the performance degradation due to non-predictability of the task the main advantage of this OS or are there some more disadvantages?

Also, what are its advantages over hard RTOS? Apart from it's not that time strict?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)? and [What guarantees do “soft” real-time operating systems actually provide](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29864/what-guarantees-do-soft-real-time-operating-systems-actually-provide)?

Comment: When you upload code into a little microcontroller (Arduino) without a proper multitasking OS, you generally have a real-time system.  The definition of "real-time" generally means that deadlines on getting an answer are well defined.  An answer in 10ms when it should come back in 5ms is just wrong, not "late".  For example, if you are filling audio buffers and you miss the fill, there is a discontinuity in the audio and you hear a loud popping noise.  Your take is ruined, and you need to do it again.

Comment: Much of the not being able to satisfy deadlines can be traced back to hardware delays, the operating system is just one of the variables.